# Is there good primer for distributional macroeconomics?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, matlab

Distributional macroeconomics (for example; works of Ben Moll) seems to be more and more popular these days.

Is there any good primer for student that wants to try to get into this new field? I am also interested in sources that go over the matlab/octave codes/techniques for this type of modeling.